# Error with run php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I was trying to run command `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

I was getting an error :

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\DoctrineCommandHelper::setApplicationEntityMan
ager() must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application, instance 
of Application given, called in /var/www/xxx/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-
bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/Proxy/UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php on line 
69 and defined in /var/www/xxx/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-
bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/Proxy/DoctrineCommandHelper.php on line 34
```

Code I found:

```
abstract class DoctrineCommandHelper
{
    /**
     * Convenience method to push the helper sets of a given entity manager into the application.
     *
     * @param Application $application
     * @param string      $emName
     */
    static public function setApplicationEntityManager(Application $application, $emName)
    {
        /** @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
        $em = $application->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager($emName);
        $helperSet = $application->getHelperSet();
        $helperSet->set(new ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()), 'db');
        $helperSet->set(new EntityManagerHelper($em), 'em');
    }
```

UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand.php on line 69

```
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    DoctrineCommandHelper::setApplicationEntityManager($this->getApplication(), $input->getOption('em'));

    parent::execute($input, $output);
}
```

I can't solve it, anybody knows the solution?

Info from composer:

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
```

Comment: Honestly I don't know, how Can I test it? Maybe the problem is wrong version of Doctrine?

Comment: Remove the cache and vendor directories and then reinstall with composer.  Your json looks correct.  Were you trying to update from an earlier Symfony version?

Comment: I removed the cache and vendors after that I reinstalled vendors with composer but I still have the same bug. I have an idea how to resolve this problem, I will try to install 'empty' symfony2 instance then I test this command with some simple entities. Is any option for copy entities into new project and than generate database schema? Sorry, about my English if you can't understand please let me know.